# RStudio version control timestamps incorrect by 4 hours

Tags: r, git, version-control, rstudio

I just setup version control in RStudio (letting RStudio add a Git repository to my existing RStudio project). However, when I use RStudio's Tools->Version Control->History functionality, the timestamps listed for my commits are 4 hours ahead of what they should be. But if I run `git log` from the terminal the correct timestamps are shown, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with Git. Any idea what might be causing this? I'm using the newest version of RStudio on a Mac.

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue?